# How to use hexojs with a different source_dir and base_dir?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hexo

I have developed an open source API documentation tool using hexo.js called "Whiteboard" - https://github.com/mpociot/whiteboard

Right now it works by cloning the repository, modifying the `source` folder content and basically running `hexo serve` or `hexo generate` to create the output result.

Now I want to provide a nodeJS module so I could use the API documentation tool like this:

```
var Whiteboard = require('whiteboard-api');
Whiteboard.generate(source_folder, target_folder);
```

My problem is, that hexo expects the `themes` folder and the `source` folder to be in the same directory.
But in my case, the theme would be located inside the node-modules folder containing my package, while the source folder could be somewhere completely different.

Has anyone built something similar already?

Basically I want to be able to call hexo like this:

```
var hexo = new Hexo(DIRECTORY_CONTAINING_THE_THEME, {
    config: DIRECTORY_CONTAINING_THE_THEME + '_config.yml',
    source_dir: CUSTOM_SOURCE_DIRECTORY,
    public_dir: CUSTOM_PUBLIC_DIRECTORY
});
```

I tried setting both the `source_dir` and the `public_dir` on the hexo object, but behind the scenes hexo tries to load the files from the initially given directories.

Can someone help me with this? Is this even possible with the regular hexojs module, or do I need to fork it and modify it to my needs?

Thank you,

Marcel

Answer (score 0):

When you do `hexo init <folder>` the folder gets a `_config.yml`. In this file you can change the source folder on the line `source_dir: source` and the public folder on the line `public_dir: public`. I'm not sure if you can provide an absolute path or use `../` to get out of the current folder. I *have* been able to change to folders within the current directory.

The theme folder seems to be baked deeper into the code since it is `theme: THEME` where THEME is located in the theme folder. I don't have any suggestions here.